# What might cause a a dock icon to have pixellated noise?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics

This is possibly a non-issue, but the Finder icon that appears when you Cmd + Tab has some strange graphical noise on the top. I can't remember how long ago it happened, or if I made anything strange before it appeared.

Does anybody have an idea of why this happens? I'm on a 13' MacBook Air 2011 with 10.7.5.

[image]

Comment: And it's only on your Finder icon?

Comment: @Michiel yes, it only appear over the finder icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely the Finder's application icon is corrupted.

To check, navigate to `/System/Library/CoreServices/` and select `Finder.app`.  Get information on the file and see what the icon looks like.

I'm not sure where you can get a replacement icon (maybe another computer or the install disks with some package exploration).  I'd post mine here but for Apple's remarkably strict copyright lawyers.

--SOLUTION--

Navigate to ~/Library/Preferences and move the com.apple.dock.plist file to your desktop. This may result in your dock items needing to be reloaded. Logout and back in.

Comment: Good clue, but icon looks OK if I do Get Info. Hmmm...

Comment: In that case it's probably your dock.  Have you tried logging out and back in or restarting your machine?

Comment: Hmmm if it's the dock then it might be related to this other problem I have http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75150/sudden-flash-of-gray-in-the-background. It happens even if I restart but the dock is a good clue.

Comment: Now this is weird, it's getting progressively worse: http://imgur.com/jHr3q3y

Comment: Navigate to ~/Library/Preferences and move the com.apple.dock.plist file to your desktop.  This may result in your desktop needing to be reloaded.  Logout and back in.  If the distortion is not gone, move the file back from your desktop.

Also, are other users (even the guest user) encountering this issue?

Comment: Yep, this solved it! Any background on why this happens?

Comment: The plist I referenced contains settings for the dock.  Sometime they get corrupted.  I'm not sure what the impact of the settings was on your dock but this is an old trick that I've been using since the days of OS 7.1.

I'm glad it worked.